# Failed to deserialize creater identity , the supplied identity is not valid error in Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been trying to get going on using the SDK to invoke a function from an installed chaincode, but I have ran into an issue, which I am struggling to resolve. 
The javascript program I built was a mix  of the test/integration/client.js file and the fabcar/invoke.js. When I run the script though, I am getting the following error when running the transaction proposal:

> error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

I know my issue is due to not using the right certificate, but I don't know where I am not using that correct certificate.  I created the crypto-config directory using the following script:

```
 ../src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build//bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
../src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build//bin/configtxgen --profile OrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
../src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build//bin/configtxgen --profile Channel --outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
../src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build//bin/configtxgen --profile Channel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/CorpMSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg CorpMSP
../src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build//bin/configtxgen --profile Channel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/EngMSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg EngMSP
```

Here is the code where I add my peer and my channel:

```
    let data = fs.readFileSync(network[org].peers['peer1']['tls_cacerts']);
          var peer = client.newPeer(
                network[org].peers['peer1'].requests,
              {
                    pem: Buffer.from(data).toString(),
                    'ssl-target-name-override': network[org].peers['peer1']['server-hostname']
                });
            console.log("- Peer set up, setting up channel");
            channel = client.newChannel(utils.getConfigSetting('channelName'));
            channel.addPeer(peer);
            data = fs.readFileSync(network.orderer['tls_cacerts']);
            channel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer(network.orderer['url']), {
                pem: Buffer.from(data).toString(),
                'ssl-target-name-override': network.orderer['server-hostname']
            });
            target.push(peer);
```

and here is the configuration of my network:

```
{
    "tmpdir": "/tmp/hfc_test_kvs",
    "channelName" : "mychannel",
    "chaincodeId" : "blockparty",
    "network-config": {
        "orderer": {
            "url": "grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050",
            "server-hostname": "orderer.example.com",
            "tls_cacerts": "./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem"
        },
        "org1": {
            "name": "Corp",
            "mspid": "CorpMSP",
            "username": "Admin",
            "peers": {
                "peer1": {
                    "requests": "grpcs://peer0.corp.example.com:7051",
                    "events": "grpcs://peer0.corp.example.com:7053",
                    "server-hostname": "peer0.corp.example.com",
                    "tls_cacerts": "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/corp.example.com/peers/peer0.corp.example.com/tls/server.crt"
                },
            "admin": {
                "key": "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/corp.example.com/users/Admin@corp.example.com/msp/keystore",
                "cert": "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/corp.example.com/users/Admin@corp.example.com/msp/signcerts"
            }
        },
```

As requested, here are some snippets of my crypto-config.yaml:

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Corp
    Domain: corp.example.com
    Specs:
      - Hostname: peer0
      - Hostname: peer1
      - Hostname: peer2
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

and my configtx.yaml:

> ```
> Profiles:
>
>     OrdererGenesis:
>         Orderer:
>             <<: *OrdererDefaults
>             Organizations:
>                 - *OrdererOrg
>         Consortiums:
>             SampleConsortium:
>                 Organizations:
>                     - *Corp
>                     - *Eng
>     Channel:
>         Consortium: SampleConsortium
>         Application:
>             <<: *ApplicationDefaults
>             Organizations:
>                 - *Corp
>                 - *Eng
>
> ################################################################################
> #
> #   Section: Organizations
> #
> #   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
> #   be referenced later in the configuration.
> #
> ################################################################################
> Organizations:
>
>     # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
>     # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
>     - &OrdererOrg
>         # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
>         # of the fabric.git development environment
>         Name: OrdererOrg
>
>         # ID to load the MSP definition as
>         ID: OrdererMSP
>
>         # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
>         MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp
>
>     - &Corp
>         # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
>         # of the fabric.git development environment
>         Name: CorpMSP
>
>         # ID to load the MSP definition as
>         ID: CorpMSP
>
>         MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/corp.example.com/msp
>
>         AnchorPeers:
>             # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
>             # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
>             # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
>             - Host: peer0.corp.example.com
>               Port: 7051
> ```

Any thoughts on which certificate I am supposed to use to properly submit the transaction proposal and then the transaction? I am not using a ca-server and I am not using the docker containers either. The environment works as I am able to invoke the chaincode using `peer chaincode invoke` command, so I know it works, but I am not sure which certificate, I am supposed to use in the `client.newPeer` and the `client.newChannel` functions.

Thanks a lot for reading,
Bertrand.

Comment: can you post snippets of crypto-config.yaml and configtx.yaml?

Comment: Done. Added requested code snippets. :)

Comment: Have you intentionally omitted definitions of `Eng` organization?

Comment: Also, I'm a but confused with your last statement: "The environment works as I am able to invoke the chaincode using peer chaincode invoke command, so I know it works, but I am not sure which certificate, I am supposed to use in the client.newPeer and the client.newChannel functions." Do you able to invoke? Or you invoking and getting the error in response?

Comment: @ArtemBarger: Yes, I intentionally omitted the definition for the `Eng` organization, as it is the same as the `Corp` organization.By invoke, I mean that I can run the `peer chaincode invoke ` command and it executes properly giving me the proper result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a certificate for client Admin. Preferably signed by either corp.example.com or peer#.corp.example.com. The certificate chain for corp.example.com is already present in the your MSPDir/ca folder. So that should do the trick.